# How to add a mimetype for custom datatype for a FitnessSensorService on the manifest?

Tags: android, google-fit

I am following the documentation from:
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types
and
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/new-sensors

To create a non-shareable, custom data type.  Which is then used on the FitnessSensorService to provide sensor data.  However, I am not clear on what to put for the mime type for this custom data type:

I tried this, but does not work.

```
<service android:name=".service.MyGoogleFitPusher"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService" />
            <data android:mimeType="com.google.android.gms.fitness.data_type/com.mycompany.mydatatype" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.data_type/com.google.heart_rate.bpm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Using a public data type does work.

Does it need to be an approved Sharable Data Type for me to use the data type as a mimeType on the Manifest ?

Is it better to just push the data with a non-sharable Custom DataType using the history API ?